# Blade Nano QX Charger hacking

Tags: power, transistors, lipo

I've got a Blade Nano QX micro drone. It's awesome. It arrives with a USB charger for the 150mAh 1S lipo battery, that has one very annoying feature.
When it's charging a red LED is on, and when it's done charging the LED turns off.
Overcharging the battery will damage it, so when charging I sit by the PC (or a USB wallwart) and wait till it's done.

In the meantime I've hacked a better solution using an Arduino UNO and some passives - I've taped an LDR on the LED, and connected another LED and a small piezzo buzzer to the Arduino.
Now, when the LED is on (charging) my LED is also on (so I know what state the charger is in even though electrical tape is hiding the original LED), and when the LED turns off my LED turns off and a short melody is played on the piezzo.
This was I don't have to sit by the charger.

Before I go on and move the project to an ATTINY and create a custom 3D printed housing for everything, I wanted to ask if there's a way to cut power to the charger, so I can have it connected to USB, but stop drawing current and stop charging the battery, in a way that I can safely leave the battery plugged in but not charging anymore.

I thought about using a transistor to monitor the LED and as soon as the LED is off, connect the transistor's base to ground and have it stop providing current to the charger.

The charger only uses the vcc and gnd wires on the USB.

Several questions that I had, but don't have enough data to answer:

1. Is a standard p2n2222a bjt OK for this?
2. Is it OK to leave the battery connected to the charger even if the charger isn't connected to anything?
3. what sort of protection should I add to the circuit if the solution I thought of is adequate?

Thanks.

EDIT:

A picture of the charger (a simple USB dongle with one LED and the eflite micro connector) [image: Picture from vendor's website]

As far as schematics or datasheets go - I couldn't find any. The user manual for the charger has no specs (http://www.horizonhobby.com/pdf/EFLC1008-Manual.pdf).

Only info available is :

Input: DC 5V, 350mA
Output: 4.2V, 300mA

EDIT2:

I've created a (very) crude schematic (Eagle newbie alert).

[image]

Power comes in through the male USB connector, and goes  out to the charger through the female USB connector.
The Transistor should stop providing power to the charger as soon as the photocell resistor detects that the charger led is off.

I currently have the circuit working WITHOUT the transistor - meaning the microcontroller and the charger get their power from separate USB ports, and I have to manually disconnect the charger when charging is done.

Comment: Presumably, the LED goes off because the charging circuit has stopped charging the battery. Why would you assume otherwise? You should measure the current and see whether it drops significantly when the LED goes off.

Comment: I assume it because the drone's user manual repeatedly warns to disconnect the battery when the LED goes off.
As for measuring the current - the connection between the battery and charger uses a very small JST like connector. I can't get probes in there, nor can I source the matching connectors to create something more accessible.
The manufacturer went to great length to make sure the battery isn't connected with the wrong polarity (can't afford the voltage drop of a diode)

Comment: You said it's a USB charger. It's fairly easy to hack a USB cable to make a current measurement.

Comment: Correct. doesn't it mean i'll be measuring the current drawn by the charger? 
Oh.. You mean measure the current draw by the charger when connected with the transistor? So I'll know I have effectively shut off the power to it?
That's a good idea. 
I'd still like to know if it's OK to leave the battery connected to the charger when the charger itself isn't powered, and that I can't measure.

Comment: Without a circuit picture or schematic of the charger we can't know.

Comment: As for a one time measure of the battery, I'm sure some fine wire wrapped around your multimeter probes and inserted into the jst connector is possible.

Comment: Edited the original question and added the charger picture

Comment: Added a schematic of the circuit I thought of building